# Character group of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, characters

I am trying to compute the character group of $\mathbb{Z}$ which contains homomorphisms that map into $\mathbb{C}^\times$. I have determined that each homomorphism $\phi \in \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ may be written as $\phi(n) = \phi(1)^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, I am unsure whether there are any further restrictions I can pose on $\phi$ to properly determine $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. Any hints or comments are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There are indeed no further restrictions (you should probably prove this).

Comment: For any abelian group $G$, the group of homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}\to G$ is isomorphic to $G$, via $\varphi\mapsto\varphi(1)$, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is free cyclic.

Comment: @egreg actually because it is free of rank $1$ (or equivalently infinite and cyclic). Cyclic is not enough.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Fixed.